# script src not working for chart.js after I separated the chart to another directory in flask app

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, chart.js

This is my home.html where I want to see my chart and have the script tag. I have installed the cdn in base.html in head and just using extends in home.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block head %}
<title>Home</title>

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<hr>
<h2>Home Page</h2>
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<hr>
<script src="/static/charts/profit_ot.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<hr>

<hr>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the js of the chart which has values coming in from my route.

```js
// Global parameters:
// do not resize the chart canvas when its container does (keep at 600x400px)
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = false;

// define the chart data
var chartData = {
  labels : [{% for item in labels %}
             "{{item}}",
            {% endfor %}],
  datasets : [{
      label: '{{ legend }}',
      fill: true,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
      borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data : [{% for item in values %}
                {{item}},
              {% endfor %}],
      spanGaps: false
  }]
}

// get chart canvas
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

// create the chart using the chart canvas
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
});
```

It works perfectly fine when I donot make the file separate, that is if my script does not have src but all the code of profit_ot.js in home.html itself.

Comment: Verify your paths and check the browser console for errors.

Comment: The paths are correct as I can see my js code when I look at the source code of the site and there is no error in the browser. But the chart is not being displayed. My hunch is that the data is not being sent to the eternal javascript file.

Comment: Are you processing the JS file on the server, or serving it as written above? If the latter then it definitely won't work because your code blocks `{%...%}` are not being substituted.

Comment: Hi Jash, did you find the solution to your question? Cause I am stuck at same thing.